# Prove that the greatest integer function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is continuous at all points except at integer points.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that the greatest integer function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is continuous at all points except at integer points.

I was solving this function , now the question that arises is that I was solving this using an example i.e. A numerical value, but my teacher keeps saying that it's wrong or I have to solve it using constants such as k... Etc. Is this method wrong according to u?

i) f(x) = [x], for all x in R
==> By the definition of greatest integer function: If x lies between two successive integers, then f(x) = least integer of them.

ii) So, at x = 2, f(x) = [2] = 2 -------- (1)

Left side limit (x ---> 2-h): f(x) = [2 - h] = 1 ----- (2)
{Since (2 - h) lies between 1 & 2; and the least being 1}

Right side limit (x --> 2+h): f(x) = [2 + h] = 2 -------- (3)
{Since (2+h) lies between 2 & 3; and the least being 2}

iii) Thus from the above 3 equations, left side limit is not equal to right side limit.
So limit of the function does not exist.
Hence it is discontinuous at x = 2
So this is not derivable at x = 2
Hence Proved.

Comment: Your answer presentation is not correct. Because in these type of question answer should not be explained with help of an example but it should be explained mathematically...

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct and valid. However, you still have a way to go, since...

---

You proved:

> The function is discontinuous at $2$.

---

You have to prove:

> 1. The function is discontinuous at **all** integer points.
> 2. The function is continous at points that are not integers

Comment: Is there any easy way to solve this function?

Comment: @Jatt-Soorma Depends on what you think is easy. To a graduate student of math, the statement you are trying to prove is probably obvious. To you, it is not, so you need to put some work into it. The proof that the function is discontinuous at all integer points is similar to the one you arleady made, for example.

Comment: @Jatt-Soorma, Instead of only showing that it's discontinuous at $x=2$, adapt your argument for $x=k$ where $k$ is any integer. Furthermore, show that it is continuous in $[k+\epsilon, k+1)$ where $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $0\lt \epsilon\lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $x=2$, use $x=k$ where $k$ is an integer. Then use the same argument, making the necessary changes, to prove that the function is discontinuous at integer-valued points. Then prove that the function is continuous on any interval of the form $(k, k+1)$.